# Symfony Google Drive Api

Tags: php, symfony, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I used Symfony and I need create file in google drive and add access to write for another user to this file. I read [google api drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/php)
intsall google/apiclient

and run qiuck star, I get name for my share file. But I not find how to create new file and how to share this file for some user, this is possible ?

I find how to create file and add to quick start

[crate file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create)

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
'name' => 'Project plan',
'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'));
$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

but have error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=id: (403) Insufficient Permission' in /home/ivan/host/aog-code/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110


{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

how to correct add file and add to permission for some user to this file ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue. Please let me know.